# how can i refactor this using functional programming ideas

Tags: scala, functional-programming

how can i use functional programing paradigm to remove the 'var' in the following code snippet, i am trying to parse a json string as map[String,Object] ,if it fails, i am parse it as map[Long,Object],so the 'KEY_TYPE' is just a switch,how can i implements a switch logic in functional programming?

```
   var KEY_TYPE = "String"

  /**
    * 解析json格式 先尝试一次解析成Map[String,Object] 失败则解析成Map[Long,Object]
    *
    * @param runSnap
    * @return
    */
  def parseJson(runSnap: String): Map[Long, Object] = {
    Try {
      if (KEY_TYPE == "String") {
        JSONUtils.parseByFastJson(runSnap).asScala
          .toMap.map(entry => entry._1.toLong -> entry._2)
      } else {
        JSONUtils.parseByFastJsonLongKey(runSnap).asScala
          .toMap.map(entry => Long2long(entry._1.toLong) -> entry._2)
      }
    } match {
      case Success(result) => result
      case Failure(exception) => {
        println("json parse excepiton " + exception)
        if (KEY_TYPE == "String") {
          KEY_TYPE = "Long"
          parseJson(runSnap)
        } else {
          Map[Long, Object]()
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Your KEY_TYPE is always "String". You can change it to val. Where do you have `real` var?

Comment: @AndrzejJozwik It's not always `String`, it is changed to `KEY_TYPE = "Long"`, and then the method invokes itself again. That feels a bit like `become` in an actor system, more than an ordinary method... Apparently, it has to be reset every time the method is used, which is really uncommon.

Comment: I think the question should be clarified somewhat. There are four answers, they all seem to solve some slightly different problems. Maybe augment your question by a more detailed description of your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't use magic strings, that's error-prone. Define a little enumeration, or at least use `Boolean`. I'll use `Boolean` for `KEY_TYPE`.
2. Just pass `KEY_TYPE` as (default) parameter:

   ```
   def parseJson(runSnap: String, keyTypeIsString: Boolean = true): 
   Map[Long, Object] = {
     Try {
       if (keyTypeIsString) {
         JSONUtils.parseByFastJson(runSnap).asScala
           .toMap.map(entry => entry._1.toLong -> entry._2)
       } else {
         JSONUtils.parseByFastJsonLongKey(runSnap).asScala
           .toMap.map(entry => Long2long(entry._1.toLong) -> entry._2)
       }
     } match {
       case Success(result) => result
       case Failure(exception) => {
         println("json parse excepiton " + exception)
         if (keyTypeIsString) {
           parseJson(runSnap, false)
         } else {
           Map[Long, Object]()
         }
       }
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: thanks.but i just want try it as Map[String,Object] once,if it fails, try Map[Long,Object]. how can i do this without a mutable state?

Comment: @Beastbrook The signature of your function says that it's `Map[Long, String]`, no matter what. The mutable state is a separate issue, you'd first have to change the signature of the method to reflect the different possible outcomes. How do you want to encode this? `Either`? Custom case-classes extending sealed trait? `Map[Any, Any]`?

Comment: imagine JSONUtils.parseByFastJson is always Failure, so every time ,you have to call parseByFastJson first then call parseByFastJsonLongKey.It affect the performacne ,because i use this code in spark. So if parseByFastJson failed once,i will use parseByFastJsonLongKey since, i don't want to do it twice.Forgive my poor English,but do you get what i want?

Comment: @Beastbrook Yes, I think I know what you want. I (falsely) assumed that you want to reset the `KEY_TYPE` before every call. In this case, you cannot solve it within the method itself, you have to modify the behavior of the function from the outside, somehow. More context is needed. How is this `parseJson` called, exactly? Do you process some messages or streams with it, or is it some kind of callback?

Comment: just  rdd.map(parseJson(_))

Answer (score 0):

Isn't something like below:

```
def parseJson(runSnap: String): Map[Long, Object] = {
   Try(JSONUtils.parseByFastJson(runSnap).asScala .toMap.map(entry => entry._1.toLong -> entry._2))
   .toOption
   .orElse(Try(JSONUtils.parseByFastJsonLongKey(runSnap).asScala).toOption)
   .getOrElse( Map[Long, Object]())
}
```

Comment: sorry!but thanks.i dont want to ignore exception .i want to log it. second,this is not my logic.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more functional version of your code. It defines an object with an `apply` method which can be used just like the original function.

```
object parseJson {
  private def parseAsString(runSnap: String): Map[Long, Object] =
    Try {
      JSONUtils.parseByFastJson(runSnap).asScala
        .toMap.map(entry => entry._1.toLong -> entry._2)
    } match {
      case Success(result) =>
        result
      case _ =>
        parser = parseAsLong _

        parser(runSnap)
    }

  private def parseAsLong(runSnap: String): Map[Long, Object] =
    Try {
      JSONUtils. parseByFastJsonLongKey(runSnap).asScala
        .toMap.map(entry => Long2long(entry._1.toLong) -> entry._2)
    }.getOrElse(Map[Long, Object]())


  private val parser = parseAsString _

  def apply(runSnap: String) = parser(runSnap)
}
```

Initially `parser` is set to `parseAsString` so `apply` calls `parseAsString` which calls `parseByFastJson`. But when parsing fails in `parseAsString` it sets `parser` to `parseAsLong`. Subsequent calls to `apply` will then call `parseAsLong` which calls `parseByFastJsonLongKey` instead. The only time that both JSON functions are called is the fiurst time `parseByFastJson` fails. After that, `parseByFastJsonLongKey` is called directly by `parseAsLong`.

Using an object keeps the `var` hidden away, and storing a function in the `var` is cleaner and more efficient than testing a `String` each time.

Comment: thanks!excelent code.but still,i want just call parseByFastJson once,if it fails ,i want always call parseByFastJsonLongKey,i dont want to falling into the exception and then call parseByFastJsonLongKey

Comment: @Beastbrook Sorry, there was a typo in the function name. I have fixed that and added some explanation. This code should do what your want.